# Word selection using Ctrl+Shift+Arrows doesn't work in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> works correctly to jump between words, however when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> to select by words, nothing happens.

Anybody knows how to make it work?
(I'm using Ubuntu 16.04)

---

Output of **`cat /etc/default/keyboard`**:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Output of **`gsettings list-recursively | grep -i ctrl`**:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot-clip '<Ctrl>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot-clip '<Ctrl><Alt>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot-clip '<Ctrl><Shift>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast '<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>R'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot-clip '<Ctrl>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot-clip '<Ctrl><Alt>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot-clip '<Ctrl><Shift>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast '<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>R'
org.onboard.lockdown disable-keys [['CTRL', 'LALT', 'F[0-9]+']]
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings zoom-out '<Ctrl>minus'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings move-tab-left '<Ctrl><Shift>Page_Up'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings new-window '<Ctrl><Shift>n'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings copy '<Ctrl><Shift>c'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings zoom-normal '<Ctrl>0'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings zoom-in '<Ctrl>plus'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings move-tab-right '<Ctrl><Shift>Page_Down'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings close-window '<Ctrl><Shift>q'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings new-tab '<Ctrl><Shift>t'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings paste '<Ctrl><Shift>v'
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings close-tab '<Ctrl><Shift>w'
org.onboard.lockdown disable-keys [['CTRL', 'LALT', 'F[0-9]+']]
```

**`dconf dump / | grep -i ctrl`** produces empty output

Comment: Oh, Dima. If you switch keyboard layout with `<Ctrl+Shift>` I'm completely with you. It is old [bug 1683383](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1683383) (really in Xorg). You can try to fix it by switching to Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS. I did so and I can select text with `<Ctrl+Shift+Arrows>`.

Comment: @N0rbert, no I use `<Alt>`+`<Shift>` to switch keyboard layout

Comment: Very strange. Which session/desktop (GNOME, Unity, MATE, KDE) do you use?

Comment: I have default Ubuntu installation with Unity

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard` and `dconf dump / | grep -i ctrl` (available from `dconf-cli` package) to the question.

Comment: I just provided the requested info. Thanks for your help, but I guess it doesn't help much...

Comment: Try to set `Alt+Shift` again and more system-wide with CLI (`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`) and GUI (`unity-control-center keyboard` and/or `gnome-tweak-tool`).

Comment: I invoked `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, changed keyboard layout hotkey to `<Ctrl>+<Shift>`, disabled it, set it to `<Alt>+<Shift>`, restarted in between - still `<Ctrl>+<Shift>+<Arrows>` doesn't work for me.
It's strange it doesn't happen for other Ubuntu users...

Comment: I just added output of `gsettings list-recursively`. Not sure if it helps. I don't see any conflicting hostkeys

Comment: You can try *Guest session* for sure.

Comment: Nice idea! In the Guest session it works. Now need to understand why it doesn't work in my account... Trying to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As @N0rbert suggested, I checked Guest session and found out that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> shortcut keys work correctly there, which means it's a matter of settings in my account.

I started to backup and remove "." folders in my account and at some point I did something wrong and my Unity settings were completely reset and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> started to work correctly.

To my regret I didn't correctly backup my wrong settings, so at this point I can't know where exactly these settings are saved, but I'm sure it's related to some Unity settings...

Answer (score 3):

One thing that could cause this, is activating this feature:

**Settings/Universal Access/Pointing & Clicking/Locate pointer**

It states that you can find your mouse pointer pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, but instead, I could no longer consistently use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>.

Leaving that information here, should I do it again, at some point.

Comment: It's a pity I ran into the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS as I like both features.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today on my Fedora 34 KDE Plasma.

Here is what worked out for me:
**System Settings > Hardware > Input Devices > Keyboard > Advanced > Switching to another Layout > uncheck Ctrl+Shift.**

For people using Gnome together with Gnome Tweaks: there's a similar list with checkboxes, that can cause the same issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1176185)

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me in Ubuntu 20.04.
Open Tweaks, got to left panel Keyboard & Mouse and disable Pointer Location.
Shift-Ctl-Arrow word selection worked again for me.

Comment: As written this is not really an answer. Ubuntu does not ship with tweaks installed. A complete answer needs to say how to install, run and use tweaks.

Comment: worked for me, ubuntu 22.04 thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found to disable it the Locate Pointer option in the Settings menu in the Accessibility.

Settings > Accessibility > Locate Pointer